# How to find iOS 4 only code in iPhone project

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

i have a iPhone Project with Base SDK 4.0 and Deployment Target set to 3.0 with XCode 3.2.3. Is there an "easy" way to find out whether i use iOS 4 only API calls in my Source Code. I'm aware that i could install an old  XCode to run my project against an e.g. 3.1.3 Simulator, but i hope there is a simpler way for checking this.

Anybody has an idea?

Thanks
Roland

Answer (score 2):

Set the SDK to a 3.x SDK and recompile. If you have any new errors or warnings, it's probably a sign you have 4.0-specific code, and the errors will tell you where.

Comment: The problem is that in XCode 3.2.3 you only have "iPhone Device 3.2" or "iPhone Device 4.0" to choose as Base SDK. 

Or do i miss something?

Comment: SDK 3.0 and 3.1.3 is no longer available for download from the Apple developer site.

Comment: You can download the older releases of xcode (which contain the older sdks) from here:

http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/7.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.3.3.3.1